# Разработка клиент-серверное приложения для удаленного получения скриншота

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, сокет

Пишу программу для курсового проекта, в которой необходимо разработать два скрипта: server и client.

На servere должен быть реализован графический интерфейс (пока остановился на tkinter), с помощью которого можно будет выбирать, с какого подключенного компьютера будет отображаться скриншот в окне программы.

Client - программа, которая будет работать на фоне и отвечать за подключение к серверу и периодическую отправку скриншота.

В целом, соединение между компьютерами с помощью сокета реализовать получилось, но застрял на отдельных вопросах, а именно:

1. Как реализовать графический интерфейс?
2. Как сделать так, чтобы к серверу могли подключаться более одного клиента?

Может, у кого-то был опыт разработки чего-то подобного, подскажите пожалуйста, как разобраться с этими вопросами?

Вот что пока получилось написать:

Для сервера:

```
import socket
from tkinter import *
import _thread
from time import ctime, sleep
from PIL import Image, ImageGrab
import os
import datetime

addr = ('localhost', 2300)
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(addr)
name = os.getlogin()
now = datetime.datetime.now()
now = now.strftime('%H_%M_from_')
datename = str(now) + str(name)
filename = datename + '.png' 
path1 = 'C://Users/FL1HT/Programs/clients/'+str(name)+'/'
(client_socket, client_address) = server.accept()
size = int(client_socket.recv(10).decode('utf-8'))
img_to_save = Image.frombytes("RGB", (1920, 1080), the_photo)
the_photo = server.recv(size)
    
def serv():
    while True:
        server.listen()
        print('Waiting for connection...')
        #print(client_socket)
        (client_socket, client_address) = server.accept()
        print('Connected to: ', client_address[0])
        while True:
            
            #print(size)
            #print(the_photo)
            img_to_save.save(path1 + filename)
            time.sleep(10)
            try:
                os.remove(path1)
            except PermissionError:
                continue
    
    server.close()
    print('server closed')
    
def servur():
    
    _thread.start_new_thread(serv, ())    

def gui():
    
    def ex():
        root.destroy()
        
    root = Tk()
    root.resizable(False, False)
    root.geometry('1024x768')
    m = Menu(root)
    root.config(menu = m)
    fm = Menu(m)
    m.add_cascade(label = 'Server', menu = fm)
    fm.add_command(label = 'Start', command = servur)
    fm.add_command(label = 'Stop')
    fm.add_command(label = 'Client list')
    m.add_cascade(label = 'Help')
    m.add_cascade(label = 'Exit', command = ex)
    root.mainloop()
    

def main():
    
    print ('starting at: ' , ctime ())
    _thread.start_new_thread(gui, ())

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Для клиента:

```
import socket
from PIL import ImageGrab

my_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
my_socket.connect(('localhost', 2300))
print("Connected to the server")

while True:
    img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0, 0, 1920, 1080))
    photo_to_send = img.tobytes()
    
    size = len(photo_to_send)
    #print(size)
    #print(photo_to_send)
    my_socket.send(bytes(str(size), 'utf-8'))
    my_socket.send(photo_to_send)
    print('Success')
```

Хочу в код скрипта сервера добавить графический интерфейс, в котором можно будет выбирать компьютер с запущенным скриптом клиента и выводить скриншот, который будет обновляться раз в 10 секунд. Получилось реализовать отправку скриншота, но чтобы он периодически обновлялся (т.е. старый скрин в папке удалялся и делался новый) пока не вышло.

Comment: 1 - что конкретно не понятно? Точно так же, как без сокетов, потом прикручиваете взаимодействие через сокеты в отдельном потоке или процессе. 2 - нужно смотреть код, и разбираться что у вас не получается.

Comment: Еще можно не изобретать свой протокол на голых сокетах, а использовать существующие протоколы, например http.

Answer (score 0):

Попробую ответить. Имею опыт создания приложения для подключение к удаленному рабочему столу

1. Отправитель отправляет байты рабочего экрана (скриншоты грубо
   говоря), принимающий их соответственно принимает и обрабатывает.
   Способы для этого есть разные, и разные по эффективности (например
   UDP)
2. [socket.listen(ЧИСЛО)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html?highlight=listen#socket.socket.listen)